# How to put this div in center and lock everything else with light blue background

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a div,

```
<div id="messagebox" style="display: none; cursor: default">
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
</div>
```

On click event, I am showing this div using,

```
$('#messagebox').show();
```

How can I put it in center of screen and also make background light dark, I want to dropdown list to trigger code behind so want to disable everything except this div,

Comment: Please show your code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I Edited your html and added it inside tabel. Now it's working fine and always
stay in center position even on window resizing. Check below demo
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NnckT/9/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want this div to function as a modal; you can add a `<div>` covering the entire background, e.g.:

```
<div id="cover" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background-color: #fff; display:none; "></div>
```

...and then show it via the same `.show()` method:

```
$('#cover').show();
```

You may also need to play with the `z-index` property of both to get the layering correct. You could also explore [jQuery's Dialog system](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), if using jQuery UI is in the realm of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a 'modal pop-up functionality', also called 'dark box' pop-up. You can achieve the 'modal pop-up' functionality either with Javascript, or with 'pure CSS'; the latter will work even in case of Javascript disabled. Here is a link to Modal Pop-Up demo implemented as pure CSS3/HTML5 solution (no any javascripting): http://webinfocentral.com/html5/ModalPopUp.htm

Essential part of it utilizes `target` attribute as shown in the listing below:

```
/*** pop-up div to cover entire area ***/
.divModalDialog  {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*! important !*/
    display:none;
    /* last attribute set darkness on scale: 0...1.0 */
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    text-align:center;
    z-index:101;
}
/*** ! target attribute does the job ! ***/
.divModalDialog:target  { display:block; }
```

Refer to my article (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/170049/Pure-HTML-5-CSS-3-Modal-Dialog-Box-no-JavaScript) for the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use som kind of modal plugin: Here is a couple, lots of examples out there. No reason to develop one of your own if no other requirements?

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-popup-window-tutorial-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jQuery BlockUI** Plugin to block the screen with your desired div accessible as a popup in centre of the screen

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#someButton').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#cover') }); 
    });
});
```

See demos over here: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos

Comment: can i ask, what's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //retrieve current window width
var windowHeight = $(window).height();//retrieve current window height


$('#messagebox').css('top',(windowHeight/2)+"px");
$('#messagebox').css('left',(windowHeight /2)+"px");
$('#messagebox').show();
```